# Coinmarketcap Data Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to **scrape** data from this webpage and I have only used pandas once for scraping. I want to get the **7 Day High/ Low values**. It is on the bottom of the page. What code should I write, and which modules should I use? Thanks for your time! This would help me so much!

https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use pandas again and come back when you run into problems.